Generate random points along road network without overlapping buildings
I'm working on generating random points along the road network in New York City. I have a shapefile with road accident data, and I want to create pseudo-absence points along the road lines. However, many of the points I'm generating end up on buildings.
How can I ensure that the generated points are only placed on the road network?

Well, there's always generating your points on the network (point along line).

Does it have to be using python?

You had a tag for Python but have not presented a code attempt nor mentioned how that may be relevant to your question so I have removed it.

Try this, however, you need to select your line layer. The random points are drawn along the line. In the image below, it is the same line, however line "1" is a single line and line "2" is a multiline. In the code the total number of points is 100. They will be drawn along the single geometry. If you want to put 100 points in each segment, you will need to convert the multipart to single parts:

Here is the code:
from qgis.core import (
    QgsProject,
    QgsGeometry,
    QgsFeature,
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsPointXY
)
from qgis.utils import iface
import random

# Function to generate random points along a line
def generate_random_points(line, num_points):
    points = []
    length = line.length()
    for _ in range(num_points):
        distance = random.uniform(0, length)
        point = line.interpolate(distance)
        points.append(point.asPoint())
    return points

# Get the active layer (assumes it's a line layer)
line_layer = iface.activeLayer()
if not line_layer.isValid():
    raise Exception("No valid active line layer found!")

# Create a new memory layer for random points
random_points_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:4326", "Random Points", "memory")
pr = random_points_layer.dataProvider()
random_points_layer.startEditing()

# Iterate over each feature in the line layer and generate random points
num_random_points = 10  # Number of random points to generate per line
for feature in line_layer.getFeatures():
    line_geom = feature.geometry()
    random_points = generate_random_points(line_geom, num_random_points)
    
    for point in random_points:
        point_feature = QgsFeature()
        point_feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(point)))
        pr.addFeatures([point_feature])

# Commit changes and add the layer to the map
random_points_layer.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(random_points_layer)

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

